# RewriteRule in .htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, litespeed

I want to cloak my affiliate links and followed the guide on [Yoast.com](https://yoast.com/cloak-affiliate-links/).

And to make the affiliate URLs look nicer (e.g. from https://example.com/go/?id=product-name to https://example.com/go/product-name) they shared the following lines for the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this isn't working and it will show an 404 error when I open the home page or any other page of my site.

My website is a static HTML site hosted on a shared hosting plan on A2 Hosting (LiteSpeed).

Comment: What folder is your htaccess located in?

Comment: it's located in the root (public_html)

Comment: Is .htaccess use enabled in your apache config file? `AllowOverride All` I assume since you said shared hosting but I'd check with them anyway

Comment: @PanamaJack "You can use directives in .htaccess files to redirect requests to different URLs, control directory listings, specify custom error documents, and more. A2 Hosting web server configurations use the AllowOverride All directive to provide the most flexibility for your website." Source: [A2 Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/using-htaccess-files)

Comment: is go a real directory?

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes, /go/ is a real directory

Answer (score 0):

I think your htaccess file is in the wrong directory. Put this inside a .htaccess inside the go folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /go/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your solution works. I created a second .htaccess file with your lines and placed it inside the /go/ directory and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer since your issue is resolved.